# div html not containing input value in ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is a div on my page

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
    <input id="Submit1" type="button" value="submit" onclick="check()" />
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

On click of button, I am sending div html to my controller, it works well, but the problem is when user types something in textbox and click button, then the value in the textbox is not sent in the html.

This is how my script looks like,

```
            function check() {

                var formData = $('.myDiv').html();

                $.ajax(
               {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "/Home/SendData",
                   data: { 
                       formData: formData
                   }

               });
            }

    </script>
```

Th code in controller,

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public JsonResult SendData(string formData)
        {
            return Json("");
        }
```

The html I am receiving is

```
  <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    **<input id="Text1" type="text" value="" class="form-control"></input>**
   //here is am not getting the text enterted by user
    <input id="Submit1" type="button" value="submit" onclick="check()">
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more »</a></p>
```

Comment: Just to add note, I don't want to post data of my html textbox, I want entire html of div along with the data entered by user in textbox.

Comment: @Brian yes I want to send entire div html

Comment: Give name attribute to the input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it by setting the `value` attribute with jQuery so `.html` function could pick in up. Just add `$('#Text1').attr("value", $('#Text1').val());` before sending the data:

```
function check() {

  $('#Text1').attr("value", $('#Text1').val());
  var formData = $('.myDiv').html();

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/Home/SendData",
   data: { 
       formData: formData
   }
 });
}
```

For multiple inputs, you could add a class to identify them all (`update` in my example) and use a function to change the value of the input, for example:

```
<div class="myDiv">
  <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
  <input id="Text1" type="text" value="" class="form-control update" />
  <input id="Submit1" type="button" value="submit" onclick="check()" />
  <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
  <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

Notice i added the `update` class in `Text1`. Now, your script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.update').on('change', function() {
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
  });
});

function check() {
  var formData = $('.myDiv').html();

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/Home/SendData",
   data: { 
       formData: formData
   }
 });
}
```

So now you have one function to change all inputs, just use the same class in every input you want to change.

**UPDATE**

If all your inputs are within the same `div` you could forget about the `update` class and use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myDiv input[type="text"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
  });
});
```

You only need to add an id (`#myDiv` in the example) to the div:

```
<div class="myDiv" id="myDiv">
```

Comment: I have multiple inputs on my page. So can't really use this code. Is there any other way out?

Comment: $('#Text1').attr("value", $('#Text1').val()); This works but as I mentioned I have almost 55 textbox on my page, so this will be a real pain. Can we do something common for all textbox

Comment: @JohnyBravo Check the update, i added a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to html encode your textbox value before sending it to the server. Try disabling Validate Request from the web.config and see if text value is received properly.

Comment: Try creating a new attribute for the text field call it 'dataField' and set its value to the original value property. Asp.net mvc has no viewstate feature, thus i believe the form is not being sent with its values, you need to manually do it.

Comment: well this really isn't related specific to asp.net. 
Even if you inspect html in the browser, it doesn't contain the value entered by the user

Comment: strange browser behavior!